# Need help performing a calculation with selection from picker view data

Tags: xcode, uipickerview

I am working on a calculator app.  I have one field of entry set up for the user to select a value.  The selections are in the form of 9 inches, 12 inches, 18 inches, 24 inches, etc.  When they select 24 inches for example, I want to use a value of .055 in the calculation which will be multiplied with another value from the calculation.  Been messing around with this and having a hard time..... thanks in advance!

```
 let myPickerData = [String](arrayLiteral: "9 inches", "12 inches", "14 inches", "16 inches", "18 inches", "24 inches")

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
return myPickerData.count
}

func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return myPickerData[row]
}

func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    rebarspace.text = myPickerData[row]
    rebarspace.resignFirstResponder()
}

 if rebarspace.text != "9 inches" {
    let z = Double (0.1466)
}
if rebarspace.text != "12 inches" {
    let z = Double (0.11)
}
if rebarspace.text != "14 inches" {
    let z = Double (0.094)
}
if rebarspace.text != "16 inches" {
    let z = Double (0.088)
}
if rebarspace.text != "18 inches" {
    let z = Double (0.0733)
}
if rebarspace.text != "24 inches" {
    let z = Double (0.0550)
}

let rebar1 = Double(z! * sqft)

let x: String = String(format:"%.2f",rebar1)

totalrebar.text = "Linear Feet of Rebar Needed=\(x)"
```

I had tried assigning the numbers to the pickerview data with if let statements but keep getting warnings and then the calculation won't run right so I know I'm missing something or heading the wrong direction..... thanks again.

Comment: Okay but where is the part that doesn't run right? I don't see any `.055` in your code. The code that you've actually shown looks like it should work fine. Or isn't it? If not, explain what doesn't work. "but keep getting warnings" What are they, and on what lines?

Comment: sorry, revised the post to include that

Answer (score 0):

In a phrase like

```
if rebarspace.text != "9 inches" {
    let z = Double (0.1466)
}
let rebar1 = Double(z! * sqft)
```

... you declare `z` *inside* curly braces, so it cannot be seen *outside* those curly braces. Thus, when we get to `rebar1`, no `z` exists.

There are a lot of ways to do this, but for simplicity, just to get you started, recast it like this (I am assuming you mean `==` instead of `!=`):

```
var z = 0.0
if rebarspace.text == "9 inches" {
    z = Double (0.1466)
}
// and so on
let rebar1 = Double(z! * sqft)
```